# Switch between Docker Images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

i need some help with docker on my mac. I have a container where i run an instance of mysql and i have created it one years ago and it worked very well until today. I have used Kitematic and i don't know why my mysql container was restarted wiped. Following this guide

https://timonweb.com/posts/getting-path-and-accessing-persistent-volumes-in-docker-for-mac/

I've found in this path

```
    linuxkit-025000000001:/var/lib/docker/volumes/41ba749910c92b2ab8e4d4a538fd6d15fad29864f2068f26629a8a7bddfcb53b/_data#
```

the mysql folder with my tables. Can i repair this horrible mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found a solution. Unfortunately as i can read online and in the Docker Documentation, on Mac Os X systems (i have Mojave) you can't access via `/var/lib/docker/volumes` folder because you must access via `screen` to view this folder, as you can read in the link in my answer. So i have done these things:

- Open a terminal and use `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`
- You should see a blank screen, just press Enter , and after a while, you should see a command line prompt
- Open another terminal and write `docker run -it -v ~/Desktop:/Desktop <runs a container from an image> bash` as you can read from the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/)
- The user’s `~/Desktop/` directory is now visible in the container as a directory under `/`
- Create a file called `testOrSo` in `home` on this terminal
- Come back to the other terminal and type `find -name "testOrSo"` and press `enter` now you have the right path to that image. Copy what you want (in my case a `_data` folder) in path that find show you and choose the `Desktop` folder mounted.
- You can show your data on your Mac Desktop.

I understand that it might not be a 100% perfect explanation or that there might be a faster method but so I solved my problem. I hope it can help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in your home directory and copy the contents of the data folder in it:

```sh
mkdir ~/mysql-data
cp -r /var/lib/docker/volumes/41ba749910c92b2ab8e4d4a538fd6d15fad29864f2068f26629a8a7bddfcb53b/_data/* ~/mysql-data
```

Now start a mysql container mapping ~/mysql-data to /var/lib/mysql

Something like this:

```
docker run \
  --name mysql \
  -v ~/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some-password \
  -d \
  mysql:tag
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately the /var/lib/docker/ path doesn't exist on my mac: i can access it only via this command screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty

Comment: You can use the path from your post. In the end any way that you can copy the files locally and them map that volume works